# Encryption in disk caching Picasso android

Tags: android, encryption, picasso, image-caching

I am planning on implementing, **Picasso** with **OKHTTP** for **Disk caching** of images. But I also plan on having **encryption** on images caches on disk. What should I do? I couldn't find a single helpful link, that can guide me in the right direction. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is looking for an answer, here is how I achieved it. 
Firstly I switched to **UIL** since it provides more customization than **Picasso**.

Then I customized the built in **diskCache** mechanism.

```
 ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
    builder.threadPoolSize(5);
    builder.imageDownloader(new CustomImageDownaloder(this, new OkHttpClient()));
    builder.diskCache(new CustomDiskCache(cacheDir));
```

Now in **CustomDiskCache** just override the methods where it read bytes from network and save them to disk, read bytes encrypt them and save them. Similarly, when you are about to read from cache file, decrypt bytes and convert them to bitmap.

Hope it helps.